# Accessing object methods given as value in dictionary (AS3)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, dictionary

So I am writing a program which uses `Dictionary` to store objects. For example

```
var dictionary:Dictionary=new Dictionary();
var myObject = new myObject(var1, var2, var3);

dicionary["key"]=myObject;
```

where `var1`, `var2`, and `var3` are simply means of assigning values to variables in `myObject`.

my question is, can I access values or functions that are found in `myObject`? In `myObject` class I have some getters and setters. Can I use a getter to get the value of `var1` for example.

```
dictionary["keys"].getVar1()?
```

kind of thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just as

```
var obj:MyObject = dicionary["key"];
trace( obj.getVar1() );
```

works, you can do it without the variable, in a single line.

```
trace( dicionary["key"].getVar1() );
```

Just beware of the type, you will get errors if

- the key doesn't exist
- the value for the key is `null`
- the value for the key is of another type

So it might be a good idea to check for these things before accessing any methods directly.

---

However, if you are using Strings, a common `Object` is the usual solution. It works as an associative array:

```
var dictObj:Object = [];
dictObj["key"] = myObject;
```

The `Dictionary` on the other hand is used when you need non-string objects as keys.

```
var dictionary:Dictionary= new Dictionary();
var key:MyKeyObject = new MyKeyObject();
dictionary[key] = myObject;
```

One last note: class names are usually written in `CamelCase`

Comment: it worked flawlessly. Thank you for your quick and clear response :)